# Shellshock - "pkg upgrade bash" doesn't update bash to latest 4.3.25

Tags: bash, vulnerabilities, freebsd

I'm using `FreeBSD-9.1-p5`.

My `security run output`:

```
Checking for packages with security vulnerabilities:
Database fetched: Wed Sep 24 23:01:24 EDT 2014
bash-4.3.24
```

`pkg info bash`:

```
# pkg info bash
bash-4.3.24
Name           : bash
Version        : 4.3.24
Installed on   : Tue Sep 16 17:17:32 EDT 2014
Origin         : shells/bash
Architecture   : freebsd:9:x86:64
Prefix         : /usr/local
Categories     : shells
Licenses       : GPLv3
Maintainer     : ehaupt@FreeBSD.org
WWW            : http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/~chet/bash/bashtop.html
Comment        : The GNU Project's Bourne Again SHell
Options        :
   COLONBREAKSWORDS: on
   DOCS           : on
   HELP           : on
   IMPLICITCD     : on
   NLS            : on
   STATIC         : off
   SYSLOG         : off
Shared Libs required:
   libintl.so.9
   libiconv.so.3
Annotations    :
   repo_type      : binary
   repository     : FreeBSD
Flat size      : 6.65MiB
Description    :
This is GNU Bash.  Bash is the GNU Project's Bourne Again SHell,
a complete implementation of the POSIX.2 shell spec, but also
with interactive command line editing, job control on architectures
that support it, csh-like features such as history substitution and
brace expansion, and a slew of other features. 

WWW: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/~chet/bash/bashtop.html
#
```

`pkg upgrade bash`:

```
# pkg upgrade bash 
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Your packages are up to date.
#
```

I'm using `pkg(8)` and not `/usr/ports`. Does it mean maintainer didn't update package, yet security vulnerabilities list is already up to date?

Comment: As usual, the pkg always behind the ports :)

Comment: to all downvoters, please use comment section to comment after you downvote! without your feedback I cannot improve myself!

Comment: Most FreeBSD users still don't use pkg, therefore it's treated as a secondary service. You can see an example of that second-class service here, as 4.3.25 still isn't available. Even when the package is released, it's still not clear what sort of testing is done on updated packages, so installing a fresh package is a bit risky and runs the risk of regressions. Bash is 'tested' after release due to the fact that it's widely used, so it's important to check the forums & mailinglists before installing any FreeBSD package/port.

Comment: The downvoters were simply voting to move this to unix.stackexchange.org .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like update is out)

```
[alexus@alexus ~]$ sudo pkg upgrade bash   
Password:
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
[alexus.org] Fetching meta.txz: 100%   968 B   1.0k/s    00:01    
[alexus.org] Fetching digests.txz: 100%    2 MB   2.0M/s    00:01    
[alexus.org] Fetching packagesite.txz: 100%    5 MB   5.3M/s    00:01    
Removing expired repository entries: 100%
Processing new repository entries: 100%
FreeBSD repository update completed. 23417 packages processed:
  9022 updated, 63 removed and 155 added.
New version of pkg detected; it needs to be installed first.
The following 1 packages will be affected (of 0 checked):

Installed packages to be UPGRADED:
    pkg: 1.3.7 -> 1.3.8_1

The process will require 31 kB more space.
2 MB to be downloaded.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
[alexus.org] Fetching pkg-1.3.8_1.txz: 100%    2 MB   2.0M/s    00:01    
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
[alexus.org] [1/1] Upgrading pkg from 1.3.7 to 1.3.8_1: 100%
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
The following 1 packages will be affected (of 0 checked):

Installed packages to be UPGRADED:
    bash: 4.3.24 -> 4.3.25_1

The operation will free 64 B.
1 MB to be downloaded.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
[alexus.org] Fetching bash-4.3.25_1.txz: 100%    1 MB   1.2M/s    00:01    
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
[alexus.org] [1/1] Upgrading bash from 4.3.24 to 4.3.25_1: 100%
[alexus@alexus ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade `bash` manually from ports.

First, I made sure ports was up-to-date:

```
portsnap fetch update
```

Then, I upgraded `pkg`:

```
cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg
make BATCH=yes build
make BATCH=yes deinstall
make BATCH=yes reinstall
```

Then I upgraded `bash`:

```
cd /usr/ports/shells/bash
make BATCH=yes build
make BATCH=yes deinstall
make BATCH=yes reinstall
```

My version of bash is now up-to-date:

```
# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.25(1)-release (i386-portbld-freebsd9.3)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
...
```

The word `vulnerable` does not show up in this test below:

```
# env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo hello"
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
hello
```

Comment: thanks for that, I'm using `pkg` not `/usr/ports`, so unfortunately this isn't useful for me, but I'm sure it's useful for someone else) so on their behalf thank you!)

Comment: Shellshock was announced over 72 hours ago and FreeBSD still hasn't released a binary update. The only reasonable solution is to build Bash from ports, uninstall bash (or `mv bash bash.old` temporarily). Bash has quite the list of build dependencies, so this can be a challenge to anyone who doesn't build ports regularly.

Comment: You can use Ports to build packages, which you can then distribute to other hosts. If you have many servers, consider the `poudriere` build system https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-poudriere.html